Что делает функция test_input, которой обрабатываются все входящие данные?
Часто встречаю в РНР коде функцию, которой обрабатываются все входящие данные. Например такую
function postCliner($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = strip_tags($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  return $data;
}

Что это за код и за что он отвечает? Можете построчно его прокомментировать?

Что это за код и за что он отвечает, вам никто не ответит, т.к. это может знать только автор кода.

@SwaD не стоит так уж категорично высказываться. Понять что делает нехитрая функция из трех строчек совсем не сложно

@Ипатьев Читаем внимательно... Я не про то, что делает(3 поисковых запроса и понятно), а про то, что это такое и за что отвечает(т.е. с какой целью была написана данная функция)

@SwaD опять же, даже если не брать долгую историю этой функции в мире пхпе, по составу вполне можно понять ход мысли применяющих её персонажей.

@Ипатьев Если отбросить вопрос "Зачем", то да, в целом ясно, что делает функция

Положи его там, где взял, и больше туда не возвращайся...

Это бессмысленный набор функций у которого ноги растут из глубокой древности.
У языка РНР есть много недостатков, но самый большой из них - его простота. Позволяющая любому школьнику освоить базовый синтаксис за два дня и сразу начать писать сайты. Как следствие, большинство пишущих на РНР не понимают основных принципов как программирования, так и веб-разработки в частности. И такая неграмотность всегда становится источником многочисленных суеверий и заблуждений.
Вот эта функция как раз и является примером такого заблуждения, которое, к сожалению, нашло дорогу в кучу некачественных источников, начиная с печально известного сайта w3schools и заканчивая книгами, в частности авторства Робина Никсона или парочки Веллинг/Томпсон (Понятное дело, читать эти книги ни в коем случае не рекомендуется, даже если их можно бесплатно скачать из интернета. Читайте Дакетта или на худой конец Котерова)
Заблуждением в данном случае является идея о том, что входящие данные можно как-то один раз "обезвредить" на входе, и дальше уже не переживать за безопасность. Идея эта на редкость дурацкая. Просто потому, что все опасности очень разные, и защита всегда должны быть адресной, в каждом конкретном случае своя. А не делаться один раз от всего скопом.
Обычно в такой очистительной процедуре в разных сочетаниях встречаются следующие функции

trim() в теории убирает лишние пробелы. Но иногда может испортить входящие данные
stripslashes() это просто бессмысленная функция, которая только портит данные
htmlspecialchars() не имеет отношения к очистке входящих данных. Она должна применяться при выводе данных, а не при получении.
mysql(i)_escape_string которая по мнению многих поколений хомячков служит для защиты от коварных инъекций, хотя не имеет к ним ни малейшего отношения.
strip_tags() - это странная функция, которая скорее испортит данные, чем сделает что-то полезное. По идее, она должна вырезать из текста HTML теги. И можно подумать, что она может помочь защитить сайт от взлома или дурацких шуток. Но во-первых, её недостаточно для защиты от взлома, а во-вторых, на нормально защищенном сайте она и не нужна. Нормальный сайт всегда экранирует данные при выводе, в соответствии с требуемым форматом.
Если же не хотим допускать HTML теги, то данные надо валидировать: то есть проверить наличие тегов в тексте и если нашли - то не молча вырезать, а выдать пользователю ошибку, чтобы он сам решил, что с ними делать.

Ничего себе зоопарк, да?
Представьте себе человека, который круглые сутки носит не снимая бронежилет, спасательный круг, огнетушитель и презерватив. Ведь все эти вещи защищают же! Ну и что что большую часть времени они не нужны. Пусть будут! Вот именно такая логика и приводит к созданию подобных функций.
Но в реальности ведь никто так не делает. А все используют по мере надобности.  Идет на пожар - берет огнетушитель. Идет в атаку - надевает  бронежилет. Ну и так далее.
И в программировании должен соблюдаться тот же самый принцип: каждая мера защиты должна применяться на своем месте, причем не заранее, а в момент использования. Если передаем данные в SQL запрос, то делаем это через плейсхолдеры. Если выводим в html, то экранируем с помощью htmlspecialchars. Если выводим в яваскрипт, то экранируем с помощью json_encode. Если выводим в шелл, то экранируем с помощью escapeshellarg. И так далее.
В итоге можно сформулировать два простых правила для защиты:

Защита должна быть адресной, а не общей
Защищать данные надо не заранее, а ровно в момент использования.

Если же хочется как-то обрабатывать входящие данные, то такая обработка называется валидацией. И заключается в проверке данных и выдаче ошибки клиенту, если данные не подходят.

htmlspecialchars() не увидел там. Ну а в целом, Ипатьев, отличный ответ, с удовольствием плюсую. И плюсую вопрос, ну а почему бы и нет. Как мне кажется, это не вопрос ни о чем, а имеет хороший смысл (также как и ваш ответ), зря его так бездумно горячо минусуют, пусть и на первый взгляд и кажется все это бесполезным. Торопится народ, как всегда - делает, а потом думает, или не думает, совсем

@Sevastopol' так и представил, как сотни людей не ищут в базе знаний ответ на вопрос "как правильно работать с запросами в БД", а днями и ночами их беспокоит только один вопрос: "что это за код"...... Вы правильно заметили.... не думает народ порой совсем

@АлексейШиманский, в какой "базе знаний"? Не громко ли? Ладно, по сути: ~90% всех ваших ответов (как и моих, и других пользователей) никому не нужны, также как и вопросы, на которые мы отвечаем. Узкие они слишком. Вот и вся ваша база знаний. Факт. Избавляйтесь от этой вредной привычки, пока не поздно) Не комментирую дальше, не хочу с вами ссориться, к вам всегда я проявлял только симпатию)

@АлексейШиманский Пример: (https://ya.ru/search/?text=css+плавное+появление) первая строка, зацените, подумайте, проанализируйте. И что дальше? А вы говорите... база знаний.. просто кому-то это очень хочется, да неможется

@Sevastopol' спасибо, перепутал с на исходником с w3schools. Поправил ответ

@Sevastopol' "всех ваших ответов (как и моих, и других пользователей) никому не нужны"  --- не понимаю почему вы написали внезапно про ответы, если речь была о вопросах и что вопрос - замечательный и его не стОит минусовать............ "Пример: (ya.ru/search/?text=css+плавное+появление) первая строка, зацените"  --- похоже у вас очень мало знаний в области css, потому что это (плавное появление) совершенно правильный и легальный вопрос, т.к. такого вида свойства он предоставляет...... так что не говорите пожалуйста ерунды, если не разбираетесь в теме.

@Sevastopol' вы сейчас затронули очень важную тему. Все активные пользователи Stack Overflow практикуют двоемыслие. Умом большинство понимает, что этот сайт по идее является базой знаний. Но при этом не делают ничего, для этой базы. Не улучшают существующие вопросы, не исправляют заголовки ответов. Но главное - пишут ответы без учета их возможного переиспользования. Отвечают так, как будто вопрос задан не на публичном ресурсе, а в приватном чате. Помогают конкретному пользователю с его проблемой, а не пишут канонический ответ. Вот наш друг Алексей к примеру любитель как раз таких ответов.

@Ипатьев у вас же у самого 846 ответов. Хотя для того, чтобы сделать каноничные ответы на PHP можно спокойно уложиться в пару десятков. Возникает тот же вопрос о вашем двоемыслии ;-)   В чужом глазу соринку видим, а в своём...?))

@АлексейШиманский верно, я пишу на основании в первую очередь собственного опыта. Вот только я его осознал и сделал выводы.

@АлексейШиманский и кстати, если вернуться с исходному вопросу. Если держать в голове базу знаний, а не просто суетиться к каждой бочке затычкой и обладать опытом в предметной области то из этого вопроса вполне можно сделать канонический.
